# Como funciona o tipo de dado Symbol()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

O tipo de dado **Symbol()** foi implementado na linguagem a partir da versão 6 ou 2015, mas, não compreendi seu real uso. Olhando alguns exemplos práticos encontrado na web, vi exemplos para atribuir novos atributos a objetos:

```js
let usuario = {
  nome: "Fulano"
};

let id = Symbol("id");

usuario[id] = 1;

console.log(usuario[id]);
```

Porém se der um log no objeto vejo que o mesmo não possui tal atributo:

```js
let usuario = {
  nome: "Fulano"
};

let id = Symbol("id");

usuario[id] = 1;

console.log(usuario[id]);
console.log(usuario)
```

Se consigo acessar o **id** através do objeto `usuario`, pq no log o objeto não possui o atributo id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O detalhe do log é que ele não possui um comportamento bem definido pelo EcmaScript, por isso vemos algumas diferenças no comportamento dele em diferentes browsers, como por exemplo quando você faz o log de um `HTMLElement` no Chrome ele printa o HTML, enquanto o Firefox printa o objeto.

`Symbols` são propriedades do objeto, e eles podem ou não aparecer no seu log dependendo da implementação. Porém diferente das demais propriedades, por padrão Symbols não são enumeráveis, o que pode ser a razão de você não conseguir visualiza-lo no seu log:

```js
var obj = {
    a: 'prop a'
}

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'b',{
    value: 'prop b',
    enumerable: false
})

console.log(obj.a)
console.log(obj.b)
console.log(obj)
```

Repare que no StackOverflow a propriedade `b` não aparece no log, apesar dela existir. A diferença de uma propriedade enumerável e uma não enumerável é que propriedades não enumeráveis não são retornadas pelo método `Object.keys()` e nem são iteradas em laços `for...in`

Quanto a utilidade dos symbols... já ouvi que symbols podem ser utilizados para criar propriedades inacessíveis, ou seja, privadas, mas isso não é mais uma boa prática já que as novas implementações do JavaScript já possuem uma maneira nativa de declarar propriedades privadas.

O uso dos symbols geralmente recaem na interação com operadores do JavaScript, como o `Symbol.iterator` por exemplo que é acessado pelo operador `of` dentro de um loop `for...of`:

```js
var listaEncadeada = {
  inicio: { val: 1, prox: { val: 2, prox: { val: 3, prox: null } } },
  
  [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
    var nodo = this.inicio
    while (nodo) {
      yield nodo.val
      nodo = nodo.prox
    }
  }
}

for (var val of listaEncadeada) {
  console.log(val)
}
```

Comment: Valeu man, bela resposta.